# Java multithreading: Fast alternative to AtomicInteger wanted

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, concurrentmodification

I have a (about 250.000) Tri-State cells with status UNKNOWN, TRUE or FALSE.

All cells start as UNKNOWN. Then a set of about 60 threads (on an AMD ThreadRipper 64 core CPU) does computations and sets these Variables from UNKNOWN to either TRUE or FALSE.

Once a cell is assigned a value, it never changes.

The same value might be assigned twice to a cell if two threads figure out independently and by different strategies what the cells value should be. It doesn't matter if a thread sees a change to a cell 'somewhat' later. It must never see an intermediate value of FALSE if another thread decides to assign TRUE to a cell with value UNKNOWN. And vice versa.

The sooner a thread sees a change to a cell, the better. Under these conditions I also don't care for write reordering.

I am currently using `AtomicInteger` to implement a cell. Profiling showed me that i spend about 30% of my computation time in this class.

What can I do to improve this situation?

PS. I am doing this to create a Nonogram solver.

Comment: Have you tried using `Booealn`s (the wrapper-class) in conjunction with `volatile`? With this, one can represent a ternary state: `true` and `false` being their resprechtive counterparts and the object being `null` signaling the state of `UNKNOWN`.

Comment: Even a non-volatile field would fit your requirements: you will never see a value that no thread writes. You might see an *old* value (which means `UNKNOWN` in your case), but never a *wrong* value. And for some cases a non-volatile field might just be the fastest (if seeing the correct value "too late" carries a lower penalty than the extra cost of volatile fields).

Comment: If reads/writes to that structure are the limiting factor, then maybe a read cache in the form of a purely local copy for each thread is the solution. Do writes back to the thread-safe master copy and occasionally re-read the local copy.

Comment: Maybe you can split your cells according with your threads?
How do you access your cells? There is an order?

Comment: Out of curiosity, which method of AtomicInteger are you using to set the value?  There may be a difference in performance between the set\* methods, lazySet, compareAndSet, etc.

Comment: Contention plays a role with so many threads. abatti's suggestion about splitting the cells would help with contention.

Comment: You need to split the work up so that each thread gets 1/n cells and there is no overlap. Using a plain old int array will work because once the worker threads are finished, any subsequent reads will get the updated values.

Comment: Did you consider using an immutable data structure for your solver? Instead of changing cells in a board just record the changes from on board to the next one. See. e.g. how cons lists work internally: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons#Lists

Comment: the main question is: let a thread decides a cell must be assigned TRUE (or FALSE). Does this decision depends on previous state of the cell (is it UNKNOWN or not)? That is, does the thread reads current value before assignment?

Answer (score 0):

As we say in Germany "Einen Tod muss mann sterben", so there's no way around some kind of locking or synchronization.

**volatile does NOT fulfill your requirements.**

Consider this case:

- you have a cell with UNKNOWN state
- 2 Threads try to change the status simultaneously
- one wants to change the state to TRUE, the other to FALSE
- both may retrieve the (at time of reading, correct) UNKNOWN volatile value
- after reading the value, both Threads get interupted & resume later
- they then both update it
- maybe neither of them will win, but both think they won!

The scenario is somewhat contrived, but possible & with the kind of number-crunching you're doing, very likely. That's Murphy's Law.

It is not sufficient that multiple Threads can read the correct value from a volatile, they need to be sure that status is unchanged for the **duration of the update**, which is why there is no way around some kind of locking.

Please also note, the **double-checked locking** algorithm which is widely bandied around is (at least in Java) a miscredited **anti-pattern**. It will fail. You can read up on that in Wikipedia.

Try out the proof-of-concept program below.
It uses synchronized to solve your requirements & is rock-solid.
Performance: 1 billion accesses in 90 seconds, multi-threaded.

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class TriState {

    private static final byte TRI_STATE_UNKNOWN =  0;
    private static final byte TRI_STATE_TRUE    =  1;
    private static final byte TRI_STATE_FALSE   =  2;

    private              byte value = TRI_STATE_UNKNOWN;

    public  synchronized boolean isUnknown() {
        return value == TRI_STATE_UNKNOWN;
    }

    public  synchronized boolean isTrue() {
        return value == TRI_STATE_TRUE;
    }

    public  synchronized boolean isFalse() {
        return value == TRI_STATE_FALSE;
    }

    public  synchronized boolean doIfKnown(final Runnable runnable) {

        if (value != TRI_STATE_UNKNOWN) {
            runnable.run();

            return   true;
        } else {
            return   false;
        }
    }

    public  synchronized boolean doIfUnknown(final Runnable runnable) {

        if (value == TRI_STATE_UNKNOWN) {
            runnable.run();

            return   true;
        } else {
            return   false;
        }
    }

    public  synchronized boolean doIfNotTrue(final Runnable runnable) {

        if (value != TRI_STATE_TRUE) {
            runnable.run();

            return   true;
        } else {
            return   false;
        }
    }

    public  synchronized boolean doIfTrue(final Runnable runnable) {

        if (value == TRI_STATE_TRUE) {
            runnable.run();

            return   true;
        } else {
            return   false;
        }
    }

    public  synchronized boolean doIfNotFalse(final Runnable runnable) {

        if (value != TRI_STATE_FALSE) {
            runnable.run();

            return   true;
        } else {
            return   false;
        }
    }

    public  synchronized boolean doIfFalse(final Runnable runnable) {

        if (value == TRI_STATE_FALSE) {
            runnable.run();

            return   true;
        } else {
            return   false;
        }
    }

    public  synchronized boolean setTrue() {
        /*
         * ok to set True if its Unknown or already True...
         */
        if (value != TRI_STATE_FALSE) {
            value =  TRI_STATE_TRUE;

            return   true;
        } else {
            return   false;
        }
    }

    public  synchronized boolean setFalse() {
        /*
         * ok to set False if its Unknown or already False ...
         */
        if (value != TRI_STATE_TRUE) {
            value =  TRI_STATE_FALSE;

            return   true;
        } else {
            return   false;
        }
    }

    private static final int        SIZE      = 250_000;
    private static final TriState[] TRI_STATE = IntStream.range(0, SIZE).mapToObj(move -> new TriState()).toArray(TriState[]::new);

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

        final ExecutorService pool     = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        final SecureRandom    rng      = new SecureRandom();

        final Duration        duration = Duration.ofSeconds(90);
        final Instant         end      = Instant.now().plus(duration);
        /*
         * Following accessed TRI_STATE 1,061,946,535 times in 90 seconds on a midrange Office PC...
         */
        pool.submit(() -> {
            while (Instant.now().isBefore(end)) {
                Arrays.stream(TRI_STATE).forEach(triState -> {
                    if (rng.nextBoolean()) {
                        triState.setTrue();
                    } else {
                        triState.setFalse();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        pool.shutdown();
        pool.awaitTermination(duration.getSeconds(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Here's an example to highlight why volatile will fail:

```
public  boolean setTrue() {
    /*
     * Read out Status & if already set, we lost...
     */
    if (status != UNKNOWN) {
        return false;
    }
    /*
     * Status is Unknown here & just BEFORE doing the following, another Thread reads out Status.
     */
    /**/       status     =  TRUE;  // Update volatile Status
    /*
     * Now we can detect if that Thread modifies Status between these 2 lines of code...
     */
    return     status     == TRUE;  // Is volatile Status still True?
    /*
     * Just AFTER doing the above, that Thread updates Status to False, thinking its Unknown.
     * 
     * So now both Threads think they won & you are up a certain creek without a paddle!
     */
}
```

Comment: > one wants to change the state to TRUE, the other to FALSE`
In my reading of the OP's question this case can never occur. If multiple threads come up with a result, they  always agree on either `True` or `False`.

Comment: If by "two threads figure out independently and by different strategies what the cells value should be" it is meant that the 2 Threads always arrive at the same result, then volatile should do it.

Comment: If different threads could come to different results for the same cell, no Java feature can solve the semantic problem. But generally, a “first one wins” strategy *can* be implemented atop a `volatile` variable, of course, not with your naive code example, but with a `compareAndSet` operation.

Comment: Just a heads up that "double-check locking doesn't work in Java" is wrong as of Java 5. It *can* be made to work, since the well-defined memory model, but only when implemented correctly.